# What will the process for integrating Alibaba's Idaas SDK integration in Xamarin application to authenticate user

Tags: authentication, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, alibaba-cloud

I want to integrate alibabas idaas sdk for login process in my xamarin application.

What will be the process for same.

I'm not finding valuable resources to do same.